# Script for automatic update / restart pc after fresh install Win7

Tags: windows, updates

I'am going to install Windows 7 on 50 PC from network image. Image have not actual paths (Unfortunately, not my business). Do you know script or some reason how to automatic install all of fresh path windows 7 by one click? In current time I sit at remote desktop and handle click update / restart PC repeated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to automate windows updates on newly deployed machines. There are a lot ways you can do that :

1) Add all most recent hot-fixes to windows image you're deploying from;

2) http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/82-windows-update-agent-force-script-email-results-version-2-6?page=6 - vbs script that does what you stated in question;

3) `wuauclt /detectnow` and `wuauclt /r` - http://www.systemcentercentral.com/tip-list-of-undocumented-wuauclt-command-parameters/ ; Windows update utility and it's undocumented parameters

4) Using 3rd party application like wuinstall (good for corporate, and for 50 PC's seems like overkill);

5) method you're using now :)

6) Powershell. A must for network administrator to know and use.